# Add a flash message and redirect after successfull login and logout using FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, routes, fosuserbundle

Using Symfony 2.8 and FOSUSerBundle 2.0, I'm trying to:

1. redirect after login and logout depending on user role,
2. add custom flash message for each operation

I added a target and default_target_path parameters in my security.yml, but it only redirects to one predefined route:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            login_path: fos_user_security_login 
            check_path: fos_user_security_check
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            default_target_path: fos_user_profile_show 
            always_use_default_target_path: false
        logout:       
            path:   fos_user_security_logout 
            target: fos_user_security_login
            success_handler: app.logout_success_handler
        anonymous:    true
```

As you can see, I've already created a logout_success_handler service:

```
class LogoutSuccessHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface
{

    protected $router;

    public function __construct(Router $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function onLogoutSuccess(Request $request)
    {
        $route = $this->router->generate('my_route');
        return new RedirectResponse($route);
    }

}
```

But is it a good approach?
How to add a flash message?

What is the recommended location in the filesystem for this kind of service? I've put `LogoutSuccessHandler` inside `~/EventListener` directory, but I think it's not the proper place... What is you opinion?

Also, I'm going to prepare a similar service (redirection and a flash message) after login.

Is the following code OK?

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class LoginSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface
{

    protected $router;
    protected $session;

    public function __construct(Router $router, Session $session)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token_name(token))
    {
        $this->session->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'user.welcome' );

        $default_route = $this->router->generate('fos_user_profile_show');
        return new RedirectResponse($default_route);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is appropriate. You can add [flash message](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html#flash-messages) using the following way.

```
class LogoutSuccessHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface
{
    protected $router;
    protected $session;

    public function __construct(Router $router, Session $session)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function onLogoutSuccess(Request $request)
    {
        $this->session->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'user.logout');

        $route = $this->router->generate('my_route');
        return new RedirectResponse($route);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid:
`$request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('type', 'message');`

does not display any message after redirection.

For other operations in controller I've been using:
`$this->addFlash('success', 'user.logout');`

which correctly shows a nice 'pop-up' message.

Comment: I figured, maybe the session is being destroyed during the process and added this to security.yml:

`invalidate_session: false`

but I didn't help either.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please try to inject Session object into your logout_success_handler service.

Comment: Thank you - that did the trick :) 
I've also updated my question - I appreciate if you could take  a look at it.

Comment: In my opinion, best place for authentication handlers is ~/Handler directory inside your bundle directory. (e.g. src/AppBundle/Handler/LogoutSuccessHandler)

Comment: OK, I will move it there. How about LoginSuccessHandler - the code is in the first post?

Comment: LoginSuccessHandler's code is okay, but there is one issue: "TokenInterface $token_name(token)" should be "TokenInterface $token". Also variables in symfony2 should be named using camelCase. If you need to check user's permissions, you've also should inject AuthorizationChecker class.

Comment: Thank you, `token_name` is just a typo, I don't whyit's here.
Could you please elaborate on the AuthorizationChecker class? Why do I need it?

Comment: You'll need it in case you want to redirect users with different roles to different routes. For example, admin can be redirected to admin panel using this if statement: if ($authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {// redirect to admin panel}